# No code changed but my program is now not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a Django Post model with a user foreign key. When I create a post it normally would work and fill the user with the requested user as instructed in the serializer but on Postman I get:

```
{
    "user": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

Here is the API view:

```
class PostViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

here is the serializer:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['user', 'id', 'title', 'body', 'user_name']
    
    def get_user_name(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.user.user_name
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: you are probably not logged in

Comment: would you provide url and views

Answer (score 0):

Remove **`user`** from the `fields` of the serializer class since you are assigning the logged in user by using the **`perform_create(...)`** method

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'body', 'user_name']
    
    def get_user_name(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.user.user_name
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: when I try that I get this error: "Post.user" must be a "CustomUser" instance